# Typo3 ai image - crop not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

When I upload a ai image the crop feature of typo3 is not working. The following error is showing up:

> No image found. Could also be that image is present but that the
>   original dimensions are unknow.

I'm using imagemagick and ghostscript.

The ai image is getting processed and I can see the image preview.

I'm thankful for every help.
Cheers.

Comment: Are the width and height of the original available/set? Go the the file list and click on the file info link

Comment: There is no width or height of the image visible. Also for jpg images I can't see the dimensions there.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. You can make them visible in the metadata edit form by installing ext:filemetadata (core extension) or looking directly in the database table `sys_file_metadata` where column `file` should match the file uid.

Comment: Width and height are 0

Answer (score 0):

ai is a vector format, so the *original dimensions* are not defined at all as they could be anything.

the preview is possible as the ai image can be any size.

maybe it is a bug in the cropping process where a fixed size is assumed and you should open a forge ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that it is possible to crop vector format. This is nearly impossible even in software like adobe illustrator: if you cut a vector line than the filling will be lost (and some other properties too). In vector based software you normally have to create a mask in order to "visually crop" a vector form.

There is no chance in my opinion.

Comment: The image is getting transformed to a gif by ghostscript. It should be possible to crop the processed image.